# Is there some Emacs command that behaves as readlink -f to print the full path of a especific file?

Tags: files, find-file, path

In the terminal, I can do:

```bash
$ readlink -f docker-compose.yml
```

Which outputs:

```bash
/home/pedro/projects/docker-stuff/docker-compose.yml
```

I would like to have something like that in Emacs so that I can find the file (a similar interface to the great `C-x C-f`) and then the full file location goes to the clipboard or kill ring. Or the full path is echoed in the mini buffer. Later, it would be possible to find it on `messages`.

Is there a way to do it?

Obs.: My first instinct was trying to use `C-x C-f` which is bounded to  `counsel-find-file` in config file. After I find the file and before pressing return, I cannot move the cursor to select the whole file path and copy it. For some reason, it is blocked. See the image below - I can only move the cursor to the white characters:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expand-file-name` do the similar things like `readlink` (or `file-truename` if you want to follow the symlink as mention by @hraban).

If you want to copy file path with a similar interface like `find-file`, here are two options to achieve it:

1. use `expand-file-name` to write your copy path function and add it to `counsel-find-file` actions and call it through `M-o` when you select the file. For more details, see [ivy actions](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#actions)
2. use [embark](https://github.com/oantolin/embark) and run `embark-action w`.

Comment: Is this an Emacs command?  I can't find it with `M-x expand-file-name`. Or, is this an Elisp function?

Comment: If it is an Elisp thing, how do you use it to achieve my desire?  I tried using `eval-expression`, opening the parens `(expand-file-name ....)` . But, it did not work out.

Comment: Ok, I did it in the `eshell`. But, it was painful. There was no auto-complete to find the file. There must be a better way! Take in notice that I am not even using vanilla Emacs eshell.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer.

Comment: `expand-file-name` does not work like `readlink -f`, the latter of which explicitly follows every symlink in its entire ancestry (that's the job of the `-f`). `file-truename` does.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `file-truename` which also does an expand in `default-directory` unless the input filename is absolute.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question in the title